# How to clean dirt embedded in epoxy sealed cement floor

Tags: floor, cleaning, cement, epoxy

Three days ago I applied a [2 part epoxy sealer](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/epoxyshield/garage-concrete-floor-coatings/garage-floor-coating) over a self leveling cement floor in my laundry room. It was still a bit tacky when I walked and moved some stuff back into it. Now there are some dirt spots that seem to be embedded in the tacky parts of the epoxy. How should I go about cleaning this while also letting the epoxy thoroughly dry? I’m not sure if I should wait or try to clean up the spots now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should have waited - "a bit tacky" is not "cured" so walking on it and moving things into it was premature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had success when messing with a partly cured thermoset compound.

You will probably have to wait for it to fully cure then sand and if necessary paint over the marks.

Answer (score 0):

Dirt *embedded in epoxy* doesn't clean. You can grind it out, or try to hide it with another coat. If you grind it out, you'll probably have to recoat anyway.